# Intersection of a line with a function in parametric form

Tags: quadratics, parametrization

I have a line defined as:

> $ax + by + c=0$

and a parabola in parametric form, ie: $x = x(t), y = y(t)$, where $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ are quadratic.

To find their intersection(s), I solve the system:

> $a\cdot x(t) + b\cdot y(t) + c = 0 $

That's straight forward enough, but what if I first need to rotate the parabola by some $\theta$?  I'm having trouble getting that into parametric form, ie $x = x_\theta(t), y = y_\theta(t)$.

The context is an application that needs to predict collisions of rolling balls (the parabolic motion part) with static linear shapes (eg: edges of a bounding rectangle).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just a rotation in the plane. $X(t)=Uz$, $z=(x(t),y(t))$;
$U$ is the rotation matrix.

Comment: Yes, I can see that. But I need to express the rotation in parametric form in order to present the resulting line intersection to a quadratic solver (GSL library). There are upwards of 20 different line equations for any given parabola, each of which has to be solved for $t$.

Comment: Ah, the penny has dropped. My apologies, I'm sorry to be so obtuse!  I can see how it should be done (a simple substitution it seems). Shall I post the parametric expressions anyway as an auto-answer?  It might be of help to others. Perhaps no-one else could be that dense ... :)

Comment: yeah but keep it soft no need for it :)

Answer (score 0):

The answer, of course, is:

> $x_\theta(t) = x(t)cos(\theta) - y(t)sin(\theta)$

> $y_\theta(t) = x(t)sin(\theta) + y(t)cos(\theta)$

Thank you Toni!